# Pro Micro recognised as Micro (win10, IDE 1.8.1)

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-leonardo, arduino-micro, arduino-pro-micro

I just got this [pro-micro clone 5V](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Arduino-Pro-Micro-Leonardo-compatible-5V-16MHz-ATmega32U4-headers-UK-TESTED/251960157859?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649) and it's my first pro micro ever. After reading lots of discussions about how easy it is to brick and how it's just a smaller Leonardo, I've also found tutorials where they guide you to install custom things (sprkfun) to recognise the board, and others where it shows up as a Leonardo board.

However in my case I just plugged it in my Win10 laptop, the drivers got installed and it is automatically recognised as an Arduino Micro.
Since I haven't found people having this, and since I'd like not to brick it immediately I was wondering what's the procedure between:

1. follow sparkfun's guide for pro micro and install their custom
   drivers
2. treat it as a Leonardo (in the IDE)
3. treat it as a standard Micro (in the IDE) since it's recognised as such

Thanks!

edit: solution: it's a **Leonardo**.

Answer (score 2):

Treat it as what it is.

What windows sees it as is just what USB reports it as. It's just a name. It has no bearing on what it is or how you program it. Select the actual board that you have in the IDE, not what Windows says it thinks it is.

As a general rule: Ignore everything Windows ever says, it's full of sh!t.

Comment: yeah, but it is sh!t in carefully crafted layers of never ending annoyance ... lol